# Tikzpicture: Draw Fancy Box, Simple Arrows and Fancy Arrows for Illustration

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I want to make an illustration with fancy boxes containing texts, simple arrow and fancy arrows in this manner:

[image]

1. I want the `right arrows` to be simple arrows like `\rigtharrow`
2. I want the boxes to have the same hight and aligned with the box above or below.
3. I want every node to slightly touch one another.
4. The second simple arrow up should be a double-edged arrow, the same with the second simple arrow below.
5. All boxes should be fancy boxes with shadow, the same with all arrows pointing up.
6. The tikzpicture should be centered and be scaled to fit in a beamer frame.

**This is my MWE*

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows,shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile, shrink=5]
\frametitle{~}

%\begin{block}{~}
%\resizebox{!}{.5\textwidth}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.4em,
nodes={draw,fill=white,blur shadow},
box/.style={align=center,inner sep=1ex},
arr/.style={single arrow,
    single arrow head extend=1mm,
    execute at begin node={\strut}}]
\node (A) [box] {Problem\\ Identification};
\node (B) [arr, right=of A]{~};
\node (C) [box, right=of B] {Statistics};
\node (D) [arr, right=of C]{~};
\node (E) [box, right=of D] {Planner};
\node (F) [arr, right=of E]{~};
\node (G) [box, right=of F] {Implementation\\of Plans};
\node (H) [arr, right=of G]{~};
\node (I) [box, right=of H] {Development};
\node (J) [arr,equal size=F,  below=3ex of A,shape border rotate=90]{~};
\node (K) [box, below=of J] {Sickness};
\node (L) [arr,,  right= of K]{~};
\node (M) [box, right=of L] {Information\\ from patient};
\node (N) [arr,equal size=F,  below=3ex of C,shape border rotate=90]{~};
\node (O) [arr,,  right= of M]{~};
\node (P) [box, right=of O] {Doctor};
\node (Q) [arr,equal size=F,  below=3ex of E,shape border rotate=90]{~};
\node (R) [arr,,  right= of P]{~};
\node (S) [box, right=of R] {Treatment by\\Nurses/\\Phamasists};
\node (T) [arr,equal size=F,  below=3ex of G,shape border rotate=90]{~};
\node (U) [arr,,  right= of S]{~};
\node (V) [box, right=of U] {Good Healt\\(Healing)};
\node (W) [arr,equal size=F,  below=3ex of I,shape border rotate=90]{~};
\end{tikzpicture}
%}
%\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

[![MYy Output[![\]\[2\]][2]][2]][2]
```

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable. Missing are packages, libraries ...

Comment: I have modified it, one can now compile this. `\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows,shadows.blur}` was missing.

Comment: any other problem? Please, do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning, 
                shadows.blur, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]%
\frametitle{Block diagram ...}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2mm and 7mm,
            nodes = {draw, fill=white, blur shadow},
       arj/.style = {draw=gray, ultra thick,-Straight Barb},
       arr/.style = {single arrow, single arrow head extend=1mm,
                     minimum height=9mm, shape border rotate=90,
                     node contents={~}},
       box/.style = {text width=0.14\linewidth, align=center,inner sep=2pt,
                     minimum height=12mm, font=\scriptsize,
                     on chain, join = by  arj,
                     execute at begin node=\hspace*{0pt}},  % <---
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[start chain = A going right]
\foreach \i [count=\j] in   {Problem Identification, Statistics, Planner,
                             Implementation of Plans, Development}
{
    \node (m\j) [box] {\i};
    \node (n\j) [arr, below=of m\j];
}
    \end{scope}
\draw[arj] (m3) -- (m2);
    \begin{scope}[start chain = B going right]
\foreach \i [count=\j] in   {Sickness, Information from patient, Doctor,
                             Treatment by Nurses/ Pharmacists, Good Health (Healing)}
{
    \node (o\j) [box, below=of n\j] {\i};
}
    \end{scope}
\draw[arj] (o3) -- (o2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Inserted is correct version of image. To code is added work around for automatic hyphenation of word *Implementation* (in code marked by `% <---`).

Comment: I like it, please make arrow connecting box with `Statistics` and `Planner` a double-edged arrow. Do same to arrow connecting `Information from `Patient` and `Doctor

Comment: @DanielJames, done.

Comment: Great! For reference sake, please make arrow connecting box `Information from Patient` and box `Doctor` a double-edged arrow too.

Comment: @DanielJames, please, than make your question more clear on the first place ... done